# Embed javascript resource in custom server control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, embedded-resource, servercontrols

I'm creating my first ASP.NET server control based on a jQuery-enhanced textbox I found online. Part of the original code includes a jQuery extension file, so I need to include that with my control. (The base jQuery library is a requirement of the web application so for our purposes here we can safely assume it's already available on any page the control is used.)

I first added the javascript file as a resource and was able to write the stream in the control's Render event. While it created the HTML/javascript as wanted, the jQuery doesn't work quite right.

The second problem I have is I anticipate several instances of the control to be used on any given page, so even if the above method worked, that javascript would be constantly repeated. Yuck.

How can I include this javascript with my control but ensure only a single iteration of it is rendered? Googling has found some references to using as `[assembly]` attribute and `Page.RegisterClientScriptResource`, but I'm not too clear on that.

Comment: Are you using the ASP.NET AJAX framework?  Multiple instances does not necessarily mean that the JS file would be duplicated multiple times.

Comment: We are, but not in the context of this server control. Duplicates arise because with the above method I'm writing the contents of the javascript file in the control's Render event. Thus, multiple controls == multiple instances of same js code.

Comment: Don't write contents, rather emit the URL to the embedded resource. If you do need to emit the contents, do it once per page like I suggested.

Comment: Agreed, rendering a link will ensure that duplications are not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(getType(page), _
   page.ResolveUrl("~/scripts/jquery.js")
```

The entire point of the RegisterClientScriptResource is to prevent the page from reloading a duplicate script.

Note that the above example assumes you are working on an Intranet.  If you are working with a public website, it is better to use CDN Hosted file (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js)

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to embed it in a page and then serve it as:

```
const string JAVASCRIPT_RESOURCE = "[namespace].[class].customJS.js"
Stream st = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(JAVASCRIPT_RESOURCE);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( st );
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), 
                                             "customJS", sr.ReadToEnd(), true);
```

Another is to add `cache-control` directives. This will cause the browser to load it up from its local cache for subsequent requests. `WebResources` emit `cache` directives when they are built in release mode `debug=false`.

Comment: This is the part I'm not entirely clear on. Does the RegisterClientScriptBlock ensure only a single instance of the javascript is registered? Or will it register another copy each time my control is instantiated?

Comment: This is on the page and not on the control. So it'll be registered only once.